# What is the difference between Python’s Pandas, R’s ggplot2 and Tableau?

Tags: python, r, tableau-api

I'm a newbie to the data world. Any help at a high level for the above would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple differences. On the first level: What is the difference between Python, R and Tableau? These are basically all three entirely different tools.

**Python** is an open-source general purpose programming language. In other words, Python is suitable for a lot of tasks. You can program desktop applications, websites/servers but is also heavily represented in datascience, computational/natural sciences,...

**R** on the other hand is also considered a programming language, but specifically for datascience and statistics. This means that, out-of-the-box, R will have a lot of statistical tools and functionality whereas Python requires some third-party installation.

**Tableau** is not a programming language, but rather a visualisation software package. You can make so-called dashboards with it, that is aimed to summarizing your complex data to human-interpretable information. The main advantage is that programming knowledge is not really necessary.

Now **pandas** is a third-party, open-source python library for data science and is most known for introducing dataframes. Dataframes are popular because they are an intuitive way to work with your data. You can read and write multiple file formats as well as perform operations on your data frames, calculate some statistics, make visualizations,... Note that R does not need a similar library since dataframes are already included in the standard R package.

**ggplot2** is an open-source R library that is specifically aimed at plotting data. The equivalent library in Python would be **matplotlib**, which pandas uses as well to generate its plots.

Which tool is best for you depends on what you would like to do. If you aren't interested in learning how to program, go for Tableau. If you do want to learn how to code, you could go with Python and/or R. If you are only interested in statistics and datascience, you can go with R. However, if you are interested in other parts as well, such as machine learning, web development, ... you're better of with Python.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2 is a full-featured R library for making publication-quality statistical graphics. It has a very expressive style that makes it useful for exploratory analysis as well as final graphics for publication.

Pandas is a python library that brings the R "data frame" to python. It is not a plotting library but it interfaces with the matplotlib library to make publication quality graphics.

Tableau is a standalone application for building dashboards and interactive graphics that are linked to databases. It has a mostly graphical interface with less coding than R/Python. The dashboards made in Tableau can also be done in R/Python, but by involving other libraries as well.